# add http builder as a dependency of Groovy script

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to write a Groovy script that depends on the [HTTPBuilder library](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder). I'm trying to add this as a dependency of my script via the `@Grab` annotation shown below

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1') 
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

// rest of script omitted
```

But when I run this script I get the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar]

I've tested using `@Grab` to add other dependencies to my script, and the same problem does not occur, why can't I add HTTPBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grape may be configured to only look in your local Maven repo for dependencies. To instruct it to also check online repositories, create a config. file `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml` and add something like the following to it

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="downloadGrapes">
      <filesystem name="cachedGrapes">
        <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
      </filesystem>
      <!-- todo add 'endorsed groovy extensions' resolver here -->
      <ibiblio name="codehaus" root="http://repository.codehaus.org/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="java.net2" root="http://download.java.net/maven/2/" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```